# Print RDCL report C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the below code to print RDCL Report directly ,
but the problem in the printed page  , it is not same to what i choose in the report properties (A4), i tried to change page width and height in device info but same issue the printed paper huge and printed on 4 papers. please any idea?

```
private Stream CreateStream(string name,
  string fileNameExtension, Encoding encoding,
  string mimeType, bool willSeek)
{
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    m_streams.Add(stream);
    return stream;
}
// Export the given report as an EMF (Enhanced Metafile) file.
private void Export(LocalReport report)
{
    string deviceInfo =
      @"&lt;DeviceInfo&gt;
            &lt;OutputFormat&gt;EMF&lt;/OutputFormat&gt;
            &lt;PageWidth&gt;8.27in&lt;/PageWidth&gt;
            &lt;PageHeight&gt;11.69in&lt;/PageHeight&gt;
            &lt;MarginTop&gt;0.25in&lt;/MarginTop&gt;
            &lt;MarginLeft&gt;0.25in&lt;/MarginLeft&gt;
            &lt;MarginRight&gt;0.25in&lt;/MarginRight&gt;
            &lt;MarginBottom&gt;0.25in&lt;/MarginBottom&gt;
        &lt;/DeviceInfo&gt;";
    Warning[] warnings;
    m_streams = new List&lt;Stream&gt;();
    report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
       out warnings);
    foreach (Stream stream in m_streams)
        stream.Position = 0;
}
// Handler for PrintPageEvents
private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{   
    Metafile pageImage = new
       Metafile(m_streams[m_currentPageIndex]);

    // Adjust rectangular area with printer margins.
    Rectangle adjustedRect = new Rectangle(
        ev.PageBounds.Left - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginX,
        ev.PageBounds.Top - (int)ev.PageSettings.HardMarginY,
        ev.PageBounds.Width,
        ev.PageBounds.Height);

    // Draw a white background for the report
    ev.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, adjustedRect);

    // Draw the report content
    ev.Graphics.DrawImage(pageImage, adjustedRect);

    // Prepare for the next page. Make sure we haven't hit the end.
    m_currentPageIndex++;
    ev.HasMorePages = (m_currentPageIndex &lt; m_streams.Count);
}

private void Print()
{
    if (m_streams == null || m_streams.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("Error: no stream to print.");
    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    if (!printDoc.PrinterSettings.IsValid)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error: cannot find the default printer.");
    }
    else
    {
        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(PrintPage);
        m_currentPageIndex = 0;
        printDoc.Print();
    }
}
// Create a local report for Report.rdlc, load the data,
//    export the report to an .emf file, and print it.
private void Run()
{
    LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
    report.ReportPath = @"Doctor_form.rdlc";
    Export(report);
    Print();
}
```

protected void print_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
       LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = @"Doctor_form.rdlc";
        report.SetParameters(parameters);
        Export(report);
        Print();}
```

Comment: Try rendering as PDF instead of Image to see if that helps?

Comment: thanks dear for your reply.dear i tried this option PDF it is very good , it is generate one PDF file in the program file, then print but i am afraid of this because more than ten users will use the program so if  they use them in same time maybe one of them will print the wrong report that created by other users.i do not know if i am thinking in the correct way

Comment: The render should generate multiple temporary names for the same report render as far as I remember, so you shouldn't run into issues like that. Best is to test if concurrency will have issues

Comment: thanks dear  i use the belwo code :                    
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;
            byte[] bytes = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);   how can i print ?

Comment: Where your code says: report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
       out warnings); what the "Image" to "PDF"